# How to prove that Zp is perfect.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying the field theory, in particular, separable extension.
I know the definition of separable extension and perfect.
but I don't have any idea to prove Zp is perfect.
Help me..

Answer (score 2):

There are many equivalent definitions of what it means for a perfect field. In particular, some of these definitions makes it pretty easy to see that $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is perfect. For example:

> $k$ has characteristic $p > 0$ and the Frobenius endomorphism $x \mapsto x^p$ is in $\text{Aut}(k).$

Indeed, due to Fermat's Little Theorem, the Frobenius endomorphism is just the identity over this field.

Answer (score 1):

The following can help you:

1) Every finite extension of $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ gives you a finite field with $\;p^n\;$ elements, $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ ;

2) The field $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ is **the** splitting field of the polynomial $\;x^{p^n}-x\;$ over $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

First of all recall that a field F with characteristics p is perfect iff $F^p=F$.
Now let $F=Zp$ then char$(F)=p$.
For an non-zero element $'a'$ $\in F$ , $a$ and $p$ are coprime, so by Euler's theorem $a^(p-1)$ congruent $1 (\mod p)
                       => a^p$ congruent $a (mod p)$
and $0^p=0$ ,hence $F^p=F$. So $Zp$ is perfect for all prime $p$.